# New SVG elements in DOM, added through JavaScript, not rendered until mouseup

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

Pure JavaScript (no JQuery, D3, or other external libraries). I'm dragging SVG objects that look like columns of rectangles around. They have connecting lines between the rectangles, and when I drag one rectangle across another, I remove all  elements from the DOM, check whether each rectangle in a column corresponds to a rectangle in neighboring column, and draw a new connecting line between them if that condition is true. In the console I can see that the  elements are created immediately, but they aren't rendered until I release the mouse and stop the drag. Because I may drag across more than one column and need to compare the results at each position before deciding where to drop, I need to force the new  elements not just to be created immediately, but also to be rendered immediately, without being blocked until I release the mouse.

[Edit: In response for downvote for "not showing research," note the following (original) paragraph. Tried all suggestions I could find, mentioning the most common ones explicitly. Perhaps my research methods are unsophisticated; can you advise so that I could do a better job next time?]

Following suggestions on this site and elsewhere, I've tried adding and deleting an element from the DOM and toggling the display property of various elements, but without success.

Sample files are at https://github.com/obdurodon/drag. To run, clone and then open textual_correspondence_static_sample/test.xhtml in a browser (from the file system, so that it can find the CSS and JavaScript files to which it's linked). Grab a drag icon at the top of a column and pull left or right. Connecting lines repaint only on drop, but I need them to repaint immediately after every crossing (I'll worry about stretching them on mousemove later).

Comment: I'd put it in a fiddle. I think its too much for people to start digging about and cloning code etc unless there's a reason a fiddle wouldn't highlight the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Now available at http://jsfiddle.net/8Hts7/. But the dragging doesn't work there (could that be diagnostic?), although it does in a real browser environment.

Comment: OP here. Also available now at http://repertorium.obdurodon.org/dev/test.xhtml.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is because you are giving the lines a stroke colour in endMove() (after your `drawLines()` call).  But you are not doing that in the `swapColumns()` function.  New elements in SVG have no stroke by default.

Comment: As the great modern philosopher Homer Simpson might have said: "Doh!". Yes, that fixed the problem. And what an embarrassing rookie mistake it was. Sigh. --OP